# Space between two td or tr tags

Tags: html, css

I would like u to help me to solve something that's really, really bother me a lot.
i've got this css and html code:

```
body
{
background-color:#ffffff;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
padding-top:0px;
}
table.main-table-default
{
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
background-color:#00ffff;
width:700px;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px;
border-spacing:0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-default td
{
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-header-default
{
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
background-color:#000000;
width:700px;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-spacing:0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-header-default td
{
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-header-default tr
{
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<table class="main-table-default">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="main-table-header-default">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/OguOU5cyikI/hqdefault.jpg" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/OguOU5cyikI/hqdefault.jpg" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There's some space between images, i wanna get rid of ot, how is it possible to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: DO you really need nested table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified CSS :

```
body
{
background-color:#ffffff;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
padding-top:0px;
}
table.main-table-default
{
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
background-color:#00ffff;
width:700px;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px;
border-spacing:0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-default td
{
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
line-height:0;
}
table.main-table-header-default
{
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
background-color:#000000;
width:700px;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-spacing:0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-header-default td
{
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
table.main-table-header-default tr
{
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

You can check it out in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf965/

Comment: only change was setting lineheight: 0 to the td.

Comment: The default line-height was causing the td to have some gap in the bottom.

Comment: That's new to me too, you'll better add it to your answer. +1

Comment: OMG! I would never solve this without that tip mate, thanks a lot!