# Space between td's - once again

Tags: html, css

I've closed the last topic cause havr thought it was completely answered, but as it appear now, it isn't.
link: [Space between two td or tr tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194824/space-between-two-td-or-tr-tags)
the line-height:0; isn't very useful here, because at the original work i'm doin' it obviously with other stuff, and the thing is, this line-geight is combining all content to a very small line, except the images, i guess. I know i may do the line-height:0; to specific td and not only td, but the main point here is to get rid of the space between the td's as it was once at html 4, i think.
Hope some1 know the answer
thanks!

the ''example''

```
<table class="main-table-default">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="main-table-header-default">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/OguOU5cyikI/hqdefault.jpg" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/OguOU5cyikI/hqdefault.jpg" border="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>random text<br><Br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i've got the solution, i mean just so u'll know...
but it's very ugly. 
the way i thought to solve this, is to made a line-hight 0 to a specific td, and then make an line-hight of 100% to other td's in that specific td, but it's crazy... there's must be another way to solve it. other way it's very ugly :/

Comment: mate please post your code and simply state whats the problem, in that other old question some guy posted an answer and i dont see any spaces whatsoever.

Comment: bro, i know, but if u try to make other td with some text, it will smash all to one line. that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always good to add reset.css at the start to get rid of unnecessary spaces. I guess you haven't done it. For the time being add the following CSS

CSS:

```
table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td
{        
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
}

table
{
         border-collapse: collapse;
         border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KEK98/

Make sure during the start of the development, you are including [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css)

Comment: thanks for the reset css. i'll include such an important thing now, cause there's probably no other way to solve it as i've done it with the ''ugly code''.

Comment: @user3556123 Reset CSS is always good. It reduces cross browsers issues upto 90%. If my answer is able to solve your problem, please check it :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any whitespace (including line breaks) before closing your TD elements.

Instead of:

```
<td><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/OguOU5cyikI/hqdefault.jpg" border="0">
                </td>
```

Write:

```
<td><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/OguOU5cyikI/hqdefault.jpg" border="0"></td>
```

Alternatively, depending on your doctype, you may want to omit the closing `</td>` tag.